# Horizontal Gradient to UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add Horizontal Gradient to UIView by following way

```
extension UIView {
    func insertHorizontalGradient(_ color1: UIColor, _ color2: UIColor) {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = [color1.cgColor, color2.cgColor]
        gradient.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)
        gradient.frame = bounds
        layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
}


    if let color1 = UIColor(hexString: "364190"), let color2 = UIColor(hexString: "699cf5"){
        self.statusBarView.insertHorizontalGradient(color1, color2)
    }

    if let color1 = UIColor(hexString: "182395"), let color2 = UIColor(hexString: "5497f0"){
        self.navigationBarView.insertHorizontalGradient(color1, color2)
    }
```

But on iPhone 6Plus its not getting applied to whole UIView. But on iPhone 6 its perfect.

[image]

Comment: When is it called exactly? Before did layout subviews ?

Comment: @Larme in viewDidLoad I'm calling this.

Comment: And could you check `self.statusBarView.frame` in `viewDidLoad()` and in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to update the gradient everytime the frame of the view changes. Using an extension for it is not the best solution because you would have to override `UIView.layoutSubviews` in all `UIView` instances that use it. Instead, you could wrap the layer into a view:

```
@IBDesignable
public class GradientView: UIView {
    private func createGradient() -> CAGradientLayer {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)
        gradient.frame = bounds
        layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
        return gradient
    }

    private var gradient: CAGradientLayer?

    @IBInspectable
    public var color1: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            updateColors()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    public var color2: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            updateColors()
        }
    }

    required public init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        gradient = createGradient()
        updateColors()
    }

    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        gradient = createGradient()
        updateColors()
    }

    override public func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        gradient?.frame = bounds
    }

    private func updateColors() {
        guard
            let color1 = color1,
            let color2 = color2
        else {
            return
        }

        gradient?.colors = [color1.cgColor, color2.cgColor]
    }
}
```

and then:

```
extension UIView {
    func insertHorizontalGradient(_ color1: UIColor, _ color2: UIColor) -> GradientView {
        let gradientView = GradientView(frame: bounds)
        gradientView.color1 = color1
        gradientView.color2 = color2
        gradientView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        self.insertSubview(gradientView, at 0)
        return gradientView
    }
}
```

Note that I have made the view `@IBDesignable`, with both colors `@IBInspectable`, therefore you can actually preview the gradient in your storyboards/xibs.

Comment: can you tell me how to add this in Static tableview background ?

Comment: @Nitesh Set it to `UITableView.backgroundView` ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call it inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews` as it contains the correct frame not in `viewDidLoad` , also make sure that this function  is called multiple times , so either wrap the code inside once bool , or set only the frame of the gradient inside it

Answer (score 1):

Instead  `gradient.frame = bounds`

try

```
 gradient.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x , y: bounds.origin.y, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width , height: bounds.height)
```

as your view covering full width 
& this prevents `viewDidLayoutSubviews` multiple calls